# Matlab: Compare strings in a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, simulink, string-comparison

I want to compare two strings from  two structs. My Code is like below:

%matlab model scan

```
[variables] = Simulink.findVars('myModell');
variablesNames =[];

%save the names of all the variables in variablesNames
for t= 1:length(variables)
     variablesNames(t).Name = variables(t).Name;   
end

%scan workspace
for f = fieldnames(my_workspace)
    found = false;
    for c = 1:length(variablesNames)
        if strcmp(f{c}, variablesNames(c))        
            found = true;
            result = 'Found in Workspace: ';
        end    
        if ~found
            result = 'Not found inside Workspace';
        end
    end
    disp(['Workspace Variable: ', sprintf('%-*s',40,f{c}), result]);
end
```

**variablesNames** is a struct 1x15 with 1 field

**my_workspace** is 1x1 struct with 20 fields

I got only one variable as return.
What is wrong in this code?

Comment: `f = fieldnames(my_workspace)` ? do you mean `f = 1:numel(fieldnames(my_workspace))`?

Comment: You mean only one value in `result`? That's pretty normal as you override it everytime you loop. Try changing `result` to `result{c}`

Comment: @Ander Biguri : I tried your suggestion, but please consider that **f** is a 20x1 cell . Here is the failure:Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in stackoverflow (line 13)
        if strcmp(f{c}, variablesNames(c))

Comment: @BillBokeey: I also tried. But result contains only one variable (number 5) from variablesNames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand why are you creating a new struct  here: `variablesNames(t).Name`, therefore I just removed that part.

The modified code just iterates through the `variables` struct-array and checks whether variable `my_workspace` has a field with the name of the value stored in the `Name` field of the currently processed element, using [isfield](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfield.html).

```
[variables] = Simulink.findVars('myModell');

for i = 1:length(variables)
   if isfield(my_workspace, variables(t).Name)
      result = 'Found in Workspace: ';
   else
       result = 'Not found inside Workspace';
   end

   disp(['Workspace Variable: ', sprintf('%-*s', 40, variables(t).Name), result]);
end
```